# problem with iterator manipulation

Tags: c++, stl

i have a std::map and i am using iterator to find a certain key,value pair. After finding it i am unable to get the position of the key,value pair from the iterator. By doing another find i can get it, but i want a work around for this.

```
//mycode is this

std::map<std::string,myclass*> mymap;

size_t myfind(const std::string &s)
{

std::map<std:string,myclass*>::iterator i=mymap.find(s);

if((i==mymap.end())||((*i).second==0))
{
std::cout<<"some error\n";
}

else
{
//here i need to return the size_t value of the iterator i
}

}
```

NOTE: edited size_t as the position of key,value pair

Comment: What do you mean by "size_t value from the iterator"? size_t is a type in C, it's not a value the iterator has. Please elaborate

Comment: what is meant `size_t` value of iterator?

Comment: What `size_t` value? Your map uses a `std::string` as the key and `myclass *` as the value. I don't see any `size_t` anywhere...

Comment: Are you attempting to return an offset to the found position.  The map has a Bidirectional iterator type you can't do pointer type arithmetic on them. http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/BidirectionalIterator.html

Comment: Sorry, this just doesn't make any sense. What `size_t` value are you talking about? There are no `size_t` values in your code whatsoever.

Comment: sorry, actually i was mentioning the position of the key,value pair in the map.

Comment: @Sriram: I'm worried what you want that for.

Comment: @Sriram: The position of the pair in the map is `map::size_type`, not `size_t`. `size_t` is a woefully incorrect type to use for position in this case. `map` is not a `vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return the "position" of the result:

```
#include <iterator>
// ...

std::map<std::string,myclass*> mymap;

size_t myfind(const std::string &s)
{

    std::map<std:string,myclass*>::iterator i=mymap.find(s);

    if((i==mymap.end())||((*i).second==0))
    {
        std::cout<<"some error\n";
    }

    else
    {
        return std::distance(mymap.begin(), i);
    }
}
```

However, you are probably better off just returning the iterator!

Comment: The return type should be `mymap::size_type`, not `size_t`.

Comment: You're partially correct, AndreyT, however `mymap` is not a type.

Answer (score 0):

What does `size_t` have to do with anything? You found the key-value pair, key is a string, value is a pointer to some class. That's it. What `size_t` value did you have in mind?

Some background to put you onto right track: map and set in STL are usually implemented as balanced binary tree (red-black tree.) Each node in the tree has the value (just key for set, or pair for map,) and two of pointers to child nodes. You can think of `map::iterator` as a pointer to a node with fancy overloaded operators so, say, incrementing the iterator value moves the pointer to the next node in sort order. So there's no "`size_t` value of the iterator". It's an instance of a class that wraps a pointer to binary tree node.